# Chrome incorrect jQuery find() on XML result

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, parsexml

I am finding that Chrome, only, is not giving me the result I expect using a jQuery `find(selector)` on XML (from `$.parseXML()`).

Consider the following *much simplified* code (https://jsfiddle.net/a504caa0/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    $(function ()
    {
      var xml =
'<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
'<DataSet>' +
'  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' +
'    <xs:element>' +
'    </xs:element>' +
'  </xs:schema>' +
'</DataSet>'
;
      var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml)
      var $docElm = $(xmlDoc.documentElement);
      alert("> find('xs\\:schema').length=" + $docElm.find('> xs\\:schema').length);
      alert("find('xs\\:schema').length=" + $docElm.find('xs\\:schema').length);
      alert("> find('xs\\:schema').find('> xs\\:element').length=" + $docElm.find('> xs\\:schema').find('> xs\\:element').length);
      alert("> find('xs\\:schema').find('xs\\:element').length=" + $docElm.find('> xs\\:schema').find('xs\\:element').length);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Running this in IE 11 or Firefox reports a 1-element match for each of the four queries, which is what I expect.

However, in Chrome (57.0.2987.133) queries 1 & 3 return 1 element but queries 2 & 4 return 0 elements.  This means that:

```
$xml.find('> selector')
```

is finding a match, while

```
$xml.find('selector')
```

is not finding a match.  In other words, if queried for a direct child it finds an element, but if queried for any descendant it says it's not there!

I do not know whether this is an XML-only issue, or whether the need to use the `xs\\:` namespace is a problem.

In real life the XML is bigger and deeper, and there are times I need to query for any descendant, not just direct children.  The solution must not just work by changing the above queries (e.g. conglomerating multiple `find()`s into one or using `children()`), it must work/explain the Chrome behaviour generically on `find()` without a leading `>`.

**EDIT**:  I just tried removing all `xs:` from the XML and `xs\\:` from the `find()`, and sure enough it now returns 1 element under Chrome.  So, it looks like this is an XML-namespace in `find()` issue.  Of course, I cannot do that in real life.  It seems Chrome can find direct children with namespace prefix but not when it involves a generic descent?  Is there an acceptable workaround?

Comment: FWIW if `xs` is the only namespace, there's no need to specify it in `find`.

Comment: But as per the example you can see that `<Dataset>` is in the default namespace, not the `xs` one.  If you remove the selectors' `xs:\\\` in my JSFiddle you will see nothing gets found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this bug for chromium at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=738372.

As per response https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=738372#c10 there, this bug became fixed in Chrome #60.  Chrome now correctly searches XML with namespaces, delivering the same results as Firefox/IE 11.