# Jquery suddenly stopped parsing xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

For some browsers, for some clients, jquery suddenly stopped parsing xml.

Example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:example_namespace="https://mylink.com/wfs/example_namespace" xsi:schemaLocation="https://mylink.com/wfs/example_namespace mylink.com?SERVICE=WFS&amp;VERSION=1.0.0&amp;TYPENAME=example_namespace:TABLE&amp;REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType" numberMatched="unknown" numberReturned="1">
<gml:featureMember>
<example_namespace:TABLE fid="TABLE.15">
<example_namespace:ID>15</example_namespace:ID>
</example_namespace:TABLE>
</gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Example jquery

```
$.get(link, function(data) { //Response is xml like in example.
console.log(data) //works as before
console.log($(data).find("featureMember").find("ID").text())
//Doesn't work now for some clients, but worked before.
})
```

**EDIT:**

More general example:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a xmlns:c="http://www.example.com">
<c:b>TEST</c:b>
</a>
```

AND JS:

```
console.log($(data).find("b").text())
```

now returns: "", before returns: "TEST"

**EDIT 2:**

Similar problem:
[Cannot extract SOAP XML with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639969/cannot-extract-soap-xml-with-jquery)

> This code was originally working in Chrome last week and once Chrome
>   updated to v60 it no longer does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome incorrect jQuery find() on XML result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607774/chrome-incorrect-jquery-find-on-xml-result)

Comment: Seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=738372) which should have been [fixed in v60](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=738372#c13)

Comment: @Andreas How can the current Question possibly be a duplicate of linked Question?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `data` to `$.parseXML()` to get a `#document`, use `.querySelector()`

```
$.parseXML(data).querySelector("featureMember").querySelector("ID").textContent;
```

alternatively pass result of `$.parseXML()` to `jQuery()` and use `.find()`

```
$($.parseXML(data)).find("featureMember").find("ID").text();
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5fuLquth/

Comment: Why `$.parseXML(data)` if _"console.log(data) //works as before"_ ?

Comment: @Andreas What does _"`//works as before`"_ mean? `jQuery()`  does not return a `#document` from which to call `.find()`. `jQuery()` returns a jQuery object containing a collection of `DOM` elements. `$.parseXML()` returns a `#document`

Comment: It returns a `#document` if the content-type is set properly: https://jsfiddle.net/datLxfot/

Comment: works as before means that "console.log(data)" return parsed XML like before update of chrome.

Comment: @Andreas What are you referencing by "It"? `jQuery()` does not return a `#document`

Comment: @Andreas Where do you set the `Content-Type` for `$.post()` call at linked jsfiddle? `$.get()` and `$.post()` expect content type to be set as string at last parameter to function call.

Comment: Just use `/echo/xml/` instead of `/echo/html/`

Comment: @Andreas That does not set `Content-Type` for `$.get()` or `$.post()`

Comment: @Yas Chrome does not appear to be the issue. The issue is `jQuery()` returns a jQuery object from passed string containing a collection of elements, including `#text` nodes, not a `#document` or jQuery wrapped `[document]`. `$.parseXML()` returns a `#document` from which to search child nodes from. You can alternatively use `XMLHttpRequest()` to specifically set `.responseType` property to `"document"` to get an XML `#document` instead of an array-like object containing individual XML nodes. From where would you be trying to call `.find()` from? You would first need to filter the collection.

Comment: data.querySelector("featureMember").querySelector("ID").textContent works, but
$(data).find("featureMember").find("ID").text();
doesn't work

Comment: You need to pass `data` to `$.parseXML()` first, then pass `$.parseXML()` to  `jQuery()` `$($.parseXML(data))` to get a reference to the XML `#document` wrapped as a jQuery object, as demonstrated at code at Answer. [`jQuery()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery) call alone does not convert text into a `#document`. `.find()` searches for descendants, `jQuery()` returns an object containing a collection of elements, essentially siblings within the array-like object which may include `comment` and `#text` nodes before `document.documentElement` of XML. You would need to filter root element first

Comment: @Yas You can  use `console` to determine for yourself what `jQuery(data)` returns, and how to properly filter the object for the node value that you are trying to retrieve from the array-like object.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing XML using jQuery in this way has some browser compatibility bugs I believe. This has been a [`won't fix jquery bug`](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4208) previously.

When there are `namespaces` in the xml you can use `jquery` selectors like the below by escaping the colon:

```
.find('gml\\:featureMember')
```

or using `nodeName`:

```
.find('[nodeName="gml:featureMember"]')
```

See demo below:

```js
var xml=`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:example_namespace="https://mylink.com/wfs/example_namespace" xsi:schemaLocation="https://mylink.com/wfs/example_namespace mylink.com?SERVICE=WFS&amp;VERSION=1.0.0&amp;TYPENAME=example_namespace:TABLE&amp;REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType" numberMatched="unknown" numberReturned="1"><gml:featureMember><example_namespace:TABLE fid="TABLE.15"><example_namespace:ID>15</example_namespace:ID></example_namespace:TABLE></gml:featureMember></wfs:FeatureCollection>`;

console.log($(xml)
  .find('gml\\:featureMember')
  .find("example_namespace\\:ID").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No it is not, missing document declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: What when I don't know the namespace? Is it possible to make a .find() only with label (like before)?